# Manually Retry Job in Delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, delayed-job

Delayed::Job's auto-retry feature is great, but there's a job that I want to manually retry now. Is there a method I can call on the job itself like...

```
Delayed::Job.all[0].perform
```

or run, or something. I tried a few things, and combed the documentation, but couldn't figure out how to execute a manual retry of a job.

Comment: `Delayed::Worker.new.run(Delayed::Job.first)` [ref](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20146200/495132)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

To manually call a job

```
Delayed::Job.find(10).invoke_job # 10 is the job.id
```

This does not remove the job if it is run successfully. You need to remove it manually:

```
Delayed::Job.find(10).destroy
```

Comment: The alternative suggested by @joe is a safer better, especially if the job needs to know whether it is running in script/console or inside a job runner.
Try this to queue the job for immediate retry
Delayed::Job.first.update_attributes(:attempts=>0, :run_at=>Time.now, :failed_at => nil, :locked_by=>nil, :locked_at=>nil)

Comment: `attempts` cannot be assigned in `update_attributes` because it is a protected attribute. I just do: `dj = Delayed::Job.first; dj.run_at = Time.now; dj.attempts = 0; dj.save!;`

Comment: To do it en-masse this worked (approx 100 jobs) 

Delayed::Job.where.all.each {|dj| dj.run_at = Time.now; dj.attempts = 0; dj.save!}

Comment: I just do `Delayed::Job.where.not(last_error: nil).update_all(run_at: Time.current)`

Comment: this doesn't set the `last_error` attribute if the job fails

Answer (score 41):

```
Delayed::Worker.new.run(Delayed::Job.last)
```

This will remove the job after it is done.

Comment: It will remove it even if it fails

Comment: For all the delayed job you can do `Delayed::Job.find_each(batch_size: 100) { |d| Delayed::Worker.new.run(d) }`

Comment: @aledustet Surely not. Are you positive?

Comment: This worked for me, for a job that did not fail. Didn't try one that fails, but I really doubt it will remove it, that would be extremely surprising.

Answer (score 12):

You can do it exactly the way you said, by finding the job and running perform.

However, what I generally do is just set the run_at back so the job processor picks it up again.

Comment: There is no `perform` method for delayed job object. The closest is `Delayed::Job.find(10).payload_object.perform`, and one should not use that.

Answer (score 10):

I have a method in a controller for testing purposes that just resets all delayed jobs when I hit a URL.  Not super elegant but works great for me:

```
# For testing purposes
  def reset_all_jobs
    Delayed::Job.all.each do |dj|
      dj.run_at = Time.now - 1.day
      dj.locked_at = nil
      dj.locked_by = nil
      dj.attempts = 0
      dj.last_error = nil
      dj.save
    end
    head :ok
  end
```

Comment: You can't use update_all ebcause attempts are protected attribute

Comment: update_all uses SQL directly and thus does not invoke validations (or protected attributes etc.)

Answer (score 8):

Prior answers above might be out of date. I found I needed to set failed_at, locked_by, and locked_at to nil:

(for each job you want to retry):

```
d.last_error = nil
d.run_at = Time.now
d.failed_at = nil
d.locked_at = nil
d.locked_by = nil
d.attempts = 0
d.failed_at = nil # needed in Rails 5 / delayed_job (4.1.2)
d.save!
```

Answer (score 5):

if you have failed delayed job which you need to re-run, then you will need to only select them and set everything refer to failed retry to null:

```
Delayed::Job.where("last_error is not null").each do |dj|
  dj.run_at = Time.now.advance(seconds: 5)
  dj.locked_at = nil
  dj.locked_by = nil
  dj.attempts = 0
  dj.last_error = nil
  dj.failed_at = nil
  dj.save  
end
```

Answer (score 4):

In a development environment, through `rails console`, following Joe Martinez's suggestion, a good way to retry all your delayed jobs is:

```
Delayed::Job.all.each{|d| d.run_at = Time.now; d.save!}
```

Comment: Updating `run_at` in 4.0.1 does not appear to be enough.  I had to do the following: `Delayed::Job.where("failed_at is not null").each do |dj| dj.run_at = Time.now; dj.last_error = nil; dj.failed_at = nil; dj.save! end`

Answer (score 3):

```
Delayed::Job.all.each(&:invoke_job)
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this in an initializer file!

```
module Delayed
  module Backend
    module ActiveRecord
      class Job
        def retry!
          self.run_at = Time.now - 1.day
          self.locked_at = nil
          self.locked_by = nil
          self.attempts = 0
          self.last_error = nil
          self.failed_at = nil
          self.save!
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can run `Delayed::Job.find(1234).retry!`

This will basically stick the job back into the queue and process it normally.

Comment: Yeah, this is a clean way of putting it back in the queue to be processed and letting the workers process it normally. I would only suggest not having `Time.now - 1.day` and just using `Time.now` or `Time.zone.now`. No sense in putting it back a day (except maybe for priority) and it can add confusion if looking at this later on.