# How do you tell a specific Delayed::Job to run in console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

For some reason, Delayed::Job's has decided to queue up but not excecute anything even though I've restarted it several times, even kill -9'd it and restarted it. It won't run any jobs.

Can I , in /console, specify a specific job and tell it to work?

Ex:.. `Delayed::Job.find(x).run`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manually Retry Job in Delayed_job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312054/manually-retry-job-in-delayed-job)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

#### `Delayed::Job.find(x).invoke_job`

**NOTE: It won't run any other things like *destroying job* that was done or so on. Just running the job/task.**

Comment: Read carefully the answer's author note: _"it won't run any other things like destroying job that was done"_. I say so because I did not read it and I was getting crazy. Check the [@DavidTuite's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20146200/316700)

Answer (score 181):

You can also do it like this:

```
Delayed::Worker.new.run( Delayed::Job.find(x) )
```

Comment: this is the best answer, it removes a job after it is done. Thanks

Comment: Delayed::Worker.new.run(Delayed::Job.find(id))

Comment: I agree with @mrt 's comment, you should make sure that you run the correct job

Comment: If i want to run multiple delayed jobs of a specific queue then how can i do that? please help

Comment: The only thing this DOESN'T do is mark the row as locked.

Comment: This is a useful method to use from automated tests like rspec.

Answer (score 0):

On Heroku I had a "stuck" job and just had to run `heroku restart` for the worker/job to start again.

Comment: Thanks for the positive comment ;-)  It could be that the person asking - or people coming to this question - had the problem on Heroku.