# SSL_connect error when using delayed_job processes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl

I have a traditional rails stack(mysql,ubuntu) that uses delayed_job for processing background tasks.

today started seeing ssl_connect errors, but only from our background processes.

- The error does not happen with our main application(re: https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/issues/371)
- the error does not happen fetching from rubygems(re: http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/)
- The error does not happen when I start a rails console process and manually invoke a job(re: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4020485/1536309)

Have also tried using the [ssl_tools/doctor from @mislav](https://github.com/mislav/ssl-tools/blob/master/doctor.rb) and have no errors.

For reference error is:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
- 17 non-project frames
File "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb" line 923 in connect
File "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb" line 923 in block in connect
File "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb" line 90 in block in timeout
File "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb" line 100 in call
File "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb" line 100 in timeout
File "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb" line 923 in connect
File "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb" line 863 in do_start
File "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb" line 852 in start
File "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb" line 1375 in request
```

Answer (score -1):

Wow.

[`PID`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) stands for `process ID`, which is the strategy that computers use to keep track internal programs that are running. each process gets a PID. **Delayed jobs allows you to configure the PID directory.**

IF you are having trouble with delayed jobs, check the pids and make sure you don't have random DJ processes running on old code. That was my problem above. anytime a bug came up, someone would manually restart DJ without specifying PIDs and it would create NEW PIDs. YIKES.

**Old DJ processes running old/outdated code.**

Comment: I love using stackoverflow as my personal note taking system.